Unable to set express-session and have it save across nodejs app
I am unable to save an express-session custom value across the routes of my nodejs API.  Even when I revisit the same route, my session attribute is undefined.  I'm trying to set req.session.custom_attr = 1; and it will not save outside of the initial request.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong???

//app.js

app.use(session({
    secret: 'my s3cret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    // credentials: true
}));

//middlewear here:
app.use('/api', api);


// routes in api
// this works and returns custom_attr
router.get(`/setSession`, async (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.custom_attr = 1;
    req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error saving session');
        }

        res.json({ "message": `Database set to ${req.session.custom_attr}` });
    });
});

// next api
router.get(`/getSession`, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.custom_attr)); // undefined

        res.json(response);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'An unexpected error occured',
            error: e.message
        });
    }
});


Unable to reproduce using browser requests to visit each endpoint or using fetch to hit each endpoint. In both cases the custom sessions were set and retained. What are you using to submit the requests to /setSession and /getSession?

If using fetch cross domain then ensure you set the credentials: 'include' options so await fetch('/setSession', {credentials: 'include'}) or await fetch('/getSession', {credentials: 'include'})
